# getting text and coordinates from a tweet in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, coordinates, geo

I am looping through a series of returned tweets to get the text component and the coordinates. I have set the code up as below , this retrieves the text but not the coordinates. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have checked the returned path and part of the returned string contains eg

```
"geo":{"coordinates":[51.479361,-0.215066],"type":"Point"},
```

so there is definitly a coordinate returned. Here is my code...

```
for (NSDictionary *tweet in results) {
                 // Get the tweet
                 NSString *twittext = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

                 // Save the tweet to the twitterText array
                 [_twitterText addObject:twittext];


id jsonResult = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"geo.coordinates"];
                 if ([NSNull null] != jsonResult) {
                     if (2 == [jsonResult count]) {
                         NSDecimalNumber* longitude = [jsonResult objectAtIndex:0];
                         NSDecimalNumber* latitude = [jsonResult objectAtIndex:1];
                         if (longitude && latitude) {

                             // here you have your coordinates do whatever you like
                             [twitterLocation addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitude, longitude]];
                         }
                         else {
                             NSLog(@"Warning: bad coordinates: %@", jsonResult);
                         }
                     }
                     else {
                         NSLog(@"Warning: bad coordinates: %@", jsonResult);
                     }
                 }*/
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `check` if value obtained is `NSString` or `NSDecimalNumber`

```
if([jsonResult objectAtIndex:0] && [jsonResult objectAtIndex:1])  
{
   if([[jsonResult objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {  
       double longitude = [[jsonResult objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
       double latitude = [[jsonResult objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
    }
}
```